# Microsoft Expression Studio - autoreset after start of Expression Web 3

Tags: microsoft-expression-web

I've got a problem with Expression Web 3. Just installed Expression Studio trial form [official site](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136523.aspx) plus few adds from there. Expression Web SP1 doesn't want to be install on my machine.

When I run Expression Web application it just resets my computer. Every other tools from Expression Studio working fine.

My system is Windows XP Home SP2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServicePack3 helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/web/thread/94e0481b-01a6-4040-a8b3-3a98c24f8509